# Retrieving list of pointer variables used in a C++ program/file

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers

Is there any way i can write a method which returns all the pointer variable names used in the C++ file.

For ex:  c++ file (abc.cpp)

```
.......
//some code here
.....
emp* emp1 = do_something();
int a = 10;
student* std1 = getdata();
```

...
..

When I parse this file (abc.cpp ) i should get two variables in output.

- output

emp1
std1

Is there any way some built in methods/procedure which tells the type of variable and list only pointer type of variables.

Thanks

Comment: no,no any built-in methods & procedures, u have to built

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in method or procedure to do this in C++ itself.  However, you could find an open source c++ parser and use it to do this.

There's a stack overflow discussion on this: [Good tools for creating a C/C++ parser/analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526797/27130)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. You have to open the file and parse it's contents to find out what you  want to find out. You could use [Boost Regular Expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can't do that with standard C++ tools. My algorythm to do the job would be something like:

1. Read the whole .cpp into std::string:

   ```
   std::ifstream ifs("filename.cpp");
   std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), 
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
   ```
2. Find all strings in that string which placed between '*' and '=' symbols and place them in array std::vector - sure it's very rough algorythm but would suite for simple task;
3. For every string in this array delete all white spaces.
4. Print all array elements.

Comment: Yes, I just screwed the term "tools". I meant that it can't be done by using standard language constructions, only with help of libraries (std for example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

vector< string > types;
set< string > names;

int main() {
    types.push_back( "int" );
    types.push_back( "char" );
    types.push_back( "float" );
    types.push_back( "double" );
    types.push_back( "bool" );
    types.push_back( "unsigned" );
    types.push_back( "long" );
    types.push_back( "short" );
    types.push_back( "wchar_t" );

    // ect

    fstream in( "input.cpp", fstream::in );
    string row;
    string tmp;

    while( in >> tmp ) {
        if( tmp == "struct" || tmp == "class" ) {
            in >> tmp;
            string::iterator it = find( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), '{' );
            tmp.erase( it, tmp.end() );
            types.push_back( tmp );
        }
        row += tmp;
    }

    for( int i=0; i<types.size(); ++i ) {
        int it=-1;

        while( ( it=row.find( types[ i ], it+1 ) ) ) {
            if( it == -1 ) break;
            int spos;
            for( spos=it; row[ spos ] != '*'; ++spos );
            spos++;

            string ptr;

            while( ( isalnum( ( int )row[ spos ] ) || row[ spos ] == '_' ) && spos < row.size()  ) {
                ptr += row[ spos ];
                spos++;
            }

            names.insert( ptr );
        }
    }

    for( set< string >::iterator i=names.begin(); i!=names.end(); ++i ) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

What I basically do, is that I put the whole input program into a row, without spaces, then check for user defined structs or classes, which I insert into the types vector, and finally I search for each type if there exists something in the form `<type>*` in the row. Then, I print it.