# Analyse C++ files from a Java program

Tags: java, c++, grammar, antlr4

After several days of research I turn to you.
I search to analyse a C++ file for:

- Count the number of parameters in method/function
- Count the numbers of line in method/function
- etc...

To do this I first tried to with regex, but it has not been successful (Too many cases handled, the regex really get too illegible).

Now I try with ANTLR4. Unfortunately I can not seem to find a grammar for C + + (I find a grammar for C here https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)

(I also tried with ANTLR3 but with this grammar, I have a C++ code !!! )
http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1295920686207/antlr3.2_cpp_parser4.1.0.zip

So do you know where I can find a C++ grammar for ANTLR4?

Or do you know another way to do what I want?

Thank you in advance for your help

PS: sorry for my english, I'm French student

Comment: Where can you find a C++ grammar for ANTLR4? It's on the same shelf as the smallest positive real number, opposite the perpetual motion machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526797/good-tools-for-creating-a-c-c-parser-analyzer). If I were you I would use a pre-built parser. After having tried to use ANTLR, I would say it takes a long time to make anything good. Personally I would try [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) has a library to build AST from where you can get the info you want.

Some existing tools compute some statistics as

- [cccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/)
- [ccccc](https://bitbucket.org/jarod42/ccccc/wiki/Home)
- ...

Comment: I tried to use C{4} but it don't give all metrics I want. C{5} not work for me because I analyse just one file.

So if my file have an include statement, C{5} generate a fatal error !