# C++ program to find syntax error

Tags: c++

I am trying to code a C++ program which will read a .cpp/.c file and find the syntax error in that like missing semi colons,braces,etc. I need this program to find at least 15 syntax error. Any idea on logic like how to do it?

I came up with this for braces like to count the number of opening braces and no of closing braces and both should be equal

Comment: Create a C/C++ parser is a hard task...

Comment: Why don't you use a compiler?!

Comment: @Jarod42 syntax analysis of C is not hard task, if you go with proper tools. C++ analysis is way too harder to implement.

Comment: "I need this program to find at least 15 syntax error": what does that mean?

Comment: @Sammer look for flex and bison resources.

Comment: @Yousf I know that but I am planning to program it

Comment: @Bathsheba it will open the file read it and says like missing semi colon in line 4, mismatched braces, etc

Comment: Have fun with abstract syntax trees.

Comment: @Bathsheba it means it's homework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526797/good-tools-for-creating-a-c-c-parser-analyzer

Comment: @NemanjaBoric I need to do it in C++

Comment: @zero298 not homework

Comment: Simply *counting* the braces is no good: `int main(){}return 0;{}`. Try a state machine.

Comment: `I came up with this for braces like to count the number of opening braces and no of closing braces and both should be equal` `for(int i;{ i < n; i++}){}`

Comment: You can't simply count braces. For example, what about the *trigraph* ??< (which is an opening brace)? The point I'm making is that you will be forever having to fix edge cases which a *compiler* will gobble up with ease. @Yousf answer is reasonable.

Comment: Strings and comments containing braces will also mess with your brace counting algorithm.

Comment: This task is mission impossible for a beginner. Especially if you should program it in C++...

Comment: If he may have false positive/negative, it is doable if he choose the rules carefully.

Comment: Do you need to find ALL syntax errors? Or is it enough to find a specific set of syntax errors?

Comment: @BoM.Petersen specific set of syntax

Comment: @sameer If you can provide a list of some specific syntax errors you need to find, them you might be able help one some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [Clang compiler](http://clang.llvm.org), and [create a plugin](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html) for it to do any custom checks on the code.

Comment: I dont know what it is, I am saying that the program will open the file read it character by character or lines

Comment: If you don´t know clang, just google it. You´ll need some time to learn how to write a plugin, but (as others said before) writing such a thing from scatch is not only much work and hard work, but impossible without much experience.